# How do I fetch data in a React custom hook only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-effect

I have a custom hook that fetches a local JSON file that *many* components make use of.

**hooks.js**

```
export function useContent(lang) {
    const [content, setContent] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const signal = abortController.signal;

        fetch(`/locale/${lang}.json`, { signal: signal })
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                setContent(json);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        return () => {
            abortController.abort();
        };
    }, [lang]);

    return { content };
}
```

**/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.js**

```
import { useContent } from '../../hooks.js';

function MyComponent(props) {
  const { content } = useContent('en');
}
```

**/components/MyOtherComponent/MyOtherComponent.js**

```
import { useContent } from '../../hooks.js';

function MyOtherComponent(props) {
  const { content } = useContent('en');
}
```

My components behave the same, as I send the same `en` string to my `useContent()` hook in both. The `useEffect()` *should* only run when the `lang` parameter changes, so seeing as both components use the same `en` string, the `useEffect()` should only run *once*, but it doesn't - it runs multiple times. Why is that? How can I update my hook so it only fetches when the `lang` parameter changes?

Comment: given that this seems to be a shared state, why don't you use context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks are run independently in different components (and in different instances of the same component type). So each time you call `useContent` in a new component, the effect (fetching data) is run once. (Repeated renders of the same component will, as promised by React, not re-fetch the data.) Related: [React Custom Hooks fetch data globally and share across components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602715/react-custom-hooks-fetch-data-globally-and-share-across-components)

A general React way to share state across many components is using a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook (`useContext`). More on contexts [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You'd want something like:

```
const ContentContext = React.createContext(null)

function App(props) {
  const { content } = useContent(props.lang /* 'en' */);
  return (
    <ContentContext.Provider value={content}>
      <MyComponent>
      <MyOtherComponent>
    </ContentContext>
  );
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  const content = useContext(ContentContext);
}

function MyOtherComponent(props) {
  const content = useContext(ContentContext);
}
```

This way if you want to update the content / language / whatever, you would do that at the app level (or whatever higher level you decide makes sense).