# React: Can this custom hook replace redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I was wondering if I really need `Redux` when I can just implement a simple custom hook?

for example this is my `store.tsx`:

```
//Initial state
var _customerDue = {
  startDate: moment().startOf('day').toISOString(),
  endDate: moment().endOf('day').toISOString(),
  buyer: undefined as Guid | undefined,
  viewModel: [] as SalesVM[]
}

export function useCustomerDue() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(_customerDue.startDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(_customerDue.endDate);
  const [buyer, setBuyer] = useState(_customerDue.buyer);
  const [viewModel, setViewModel] = useState(_customerDue.viewModel);

  useEffect(() => {
    _customerDue.startDate = startDate;
    _customerDue.endDate = endDate;
    _customerDue.buyer = buyer;
    _customerDue.viewModel = viewModel;
  }, [startDate, endDate, buyer, viewModel]);

  return { startDate, setStartDate, endDate, setEndDate, buyer, setBuyer, viewModel, setViewModel };
}
```

Then I just call this in my react component:

```
const CustomerDue: React.FC = () => {
  const { startDate, setStartDate, endDate, setEndDate, buyer, setBuyer, viewModel, setViewModel } = useCustomerDue();
  .....
```

Is this code viable to replace Redux? Is this code performance fast and efficient? What are the cases when we should use `Redux` rather than this simple custom hook?

I mean because writing `Redux` store is a bit too much. Also the `switch case` on the reducer is not neat.

---

### EDIT

As @JLRishe said, `Redux` it might not necessary for my application.

For those who might find this approach helpful, for complex manipulation, we can also export `functions` for the manipulation.

For example:

```
export function useCustomerDue() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(_customerDue.startDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(_customerDue.endDate);
  const [buyer, setBuyer] = useState(_customerDue.buyer);
  const [viewModel, setViewModel] = useState(_customerDue.viewModel);

  useEffect(() => {
    _customerDue.startDate = startDate;
    _customerDue.endDate = endDate;
    _customerDue.buyer = buyer;
    _customerDue.viewModel = viewModel;
  }, [startDate, endDate, buyer, viewModel]);

  const complexManipulation = (value: ComplexValue) => {
      //Do complex operation, and set states
  }

  return { startDate, setStartDate, endDate, setEndDate, buyer, setBuyer, viewModel, setViewModel, complexManipulation };
}
```

I hope this helps.

---

### WEAKNESS

As @Nick said, if we use the hook in different components, they are not sync.

Comment: As the creators of Redux themselves would say, [you don't necessarily "really need" Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367), but my question for you would be, what happens when you need to store more than the four values you have here? Your custom hook already exports 8 properties. What happens when you need to keep track of 100 different values, or interact with them in a way that's more than simply get/set? [Redux FAQ: When should I use Redux?](https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux)

Comment: If you use this hook in two places, it seems like the data would end up out of sync. Updating in one component would set the date for that component (and in the global object), but the other component would be unaware of that change.

Comment: If your main complaints against redux is the boilerplatiness, i.e. older pattern, then I submit to you, [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/). Other than this, what you are asking is of an opinionated nature. Whether or not a custom hook could replace redux is entirely dependent on your specific project's needs. At a minimum I would say "No, absolutely not" that a single custom hook could replace the entire redux and react-redux ecosystem, utilizing the Context API and several React hooks and established design and immutable update patterns.

Comment: Do you already have a working react redux application? If so, what are the pain points you are experiencing? Are you already using redux-toolkit and rtk-query?

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding an answer directly into the body of the question. If you want to indicate that a question has an accepted answer, you can click the check/tick mark alongside the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say **no**. Because the custom hook is called in each component independently.

This means you need to store the global value somewhere (which is what Redux does). You can custom create a global variable within your custom hook code file. You can refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449641/6746457) for an idea.

**Personally,** I use [Reactive Variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/) of Apollo Client v3, which is very easy to use for simple use cases. I've used Redux myself with redux-observable and all, but I'm currently using GraphQL with Apollo. If you're looking to replace redux in your code, I suggest you to have a look into it. I found it to be a better solution than redux for managing global states.